# Is there a specific way to add data points from fetch() after a chart has been built?

Tags: highcharts

I have data which I `fetch()` and add to a time series chart once they are available. The received data are in the format

```
[
    {
        "count": 1932,
        "date": "2018-03-29T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "count": 3957,
        "date": "2018-03-28T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "count": 3864,
        "date": "2018-03-27T00:00:00"
    },
]
```

and I use `addPoint()` to update the chart.

The chart is correctly updated with the Y ("count") but the X axis is ticked by seconds.

[image]

This would suggest a wrong format of the time data. However, the following code (which builds the chart)

```
let chart = Highcharts.chart("app", {
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: "candidates",
            data: [],
        },
        {
            name: "scanned",
            data: [],
        },
    ],
})

// get candidates
fetch("https://example.com/rpc/candidat_per_day", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "limit_days": 15
        }),
        headers: new Headers({
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }),
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
        r.reverse().pop()
        r.forEach(data => {
            console.log(moment(data.date).format("x"))
            chart.series[0].addPoint([moment(data.date).format("x"), data.count])
        })
    })

fetch("https://example.com/rpc/scanned_per_day", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            limit_days: 15,
        }),
        headers: new Headers({
            "content-type": "application/json",
        }),
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
        r.reverse().pop()
        r.forEach(data => {
            d = moment(data.date).format("x")
            console.log(d)
            chart.series[1].addPoint([d, data.count])
        })
    })
```

outputs on the console numbers such as `1521414000000` or `1521500400000`. When [converting them independently](https://www.epochconverter.com/) I get respectively the 18 and 19 of March 2018 - the expected date for these data with the confirmation that they are in ms.

Worse: when trying to replicate the issue by adding these points to an existing chart, everything is OK:

```js
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  series: [{
    data: []
  }]
});

chart.series[0].addPoint([1519772400000, 5])
chart.series[0].addPoint([1520895600000, 6])
chart.series[0].addPoint([1521241200000, 4])
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

The difference I see between the replication code and the one I actaully run is the `fetch()` part (and the promises handling) but I do not see any reasons for the code not to work that way.

**I believe there is a minor issue somewhere (probably around the time handling), but after staring at the code for hours I cannot find anything wrong. What should I try next?**

Comment: any console errors

Comment: @Deep3015: no, there are no errors of any kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `format()` function returns a **String**:

```
// in console:
moment().format("x")
"1522407551509"
```

Highcharts expect the x coordinate to be a **Number.**

You can use `parseInt()` for the conversion:

```js
console.log(parseInt(moment().format("x")))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I added to your answer a tiny bit about how to convert to int